# Book Recommendation Question

Tags: discussion, off-topic, opinion-based

We have [a question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/883/looking-at-a-career-jump-into-devops-and-advice-or-suggested-reading) requesting suggested reading, the question itself is quite broad and the answers have the potential to be opinion rather than fact:

- It has three upvotes and three downvotes,
- It has three close votes.

My recommendation was to post a new Community Wiki question with suggested reading.  However, Aurora pointed out [this is now discouraged](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36758487#36758487).  I think there are a couple of approaches we could take, I will try and list these as answers, jump in with other suggestions too.

Answer (score 6):

> the question itself is quite broad

Exactly. I have been repeatedly telling in chat and the site that Devops is a huge domain. So, there are hundreds of books which can be potential answers for this question. So many that even a CW wouldn't suffice.

Instead, if I have a well-narrowed down question like:

> Can you suggest me books (and/or) resources for learning about X?

where X can be pin-pointed domains/concepts like `Devops Culture`, `Devops Hiring`, `Cloud Security`, `Serverless Infrastructure/Applications`, `Chatops`, `SRE`.

Instead, if someone askes for a book recommendation about `Devops`, I see it as very broad.  It's like asking for book recommendations for `Computer Science`. SCIP can be a potential answer, as well as CLRS by Cormen.  So, the number of answers will go on and on, and which might in fact, confuse the OP rather than helping them.

Comment: Reading between the lines, I think what the author is actually asking is for introductory books, I am inclined to answer with [The Phoenix Project](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Phoenix-Project-DevOps-Helping-Business-ebook/dp/B00AZRBLHO), [The DevOps Handbook](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Devops-Handbook-World-Class-Reliability-Organizations/dp/1942788002) and [Continuous Delivery](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Continuous-Delivery-Deployment-Automation-Addison-Wesley/0321601912) - however in it's current state I don't think it's a viable question thus I am resisting answering.

Comment: I'm with you on this, let's try the [ChatOps question for size](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/924/what-chatops-books-and-resources-are-available)

Comment: It's a good answer. I would like to add that on the Q&A format, the documentation of wiki of various tags is sometimes a good place to suggest books.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think book recommendation are something to have, answers will become outdated and so we will keep outdated content.

There's a [large Q/A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations) about this on meta.se, the problem has already be tried on many se sites and nothing valuable on long term has never came out.

Best bet is too keep those kind of talks in chat, short lived (in accuracy) answers are not something we should go for.

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with this question and questions like it here on DevOps StackExchange.  On one hand, this is exactly the kind of question that people new to DevOps will come here seeking to answer.  On the other hand, it's a very broad question.  I think we need to find a happy medium or we run the risk of devaluing the site for those who need it most- DevOps newbies.

I've never been a fan of the tendency for all "what to read" questions to be closed on StackExchange network sites.  While I understand the need to keep questions timeless and specific, there must be some way to address these types of questions other than closing them.

I agree with [Dawny33](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46/dawny33) that more specific questions about DevOps resources (books, classes, videos) should be allowed to stand.  The best resources tend to be valuable for some time, and I think we should tolerate a little timeliness in the interest of allowing these kinds of questions to be answered.